How can I play a sound based on text name?
I am making a langauge dictionary where you input a word <input id="maininput" ...> and then  outputs 2 or 3 synonyms in different text fields   <a id="synonym1" ...>, <a id="synonym2".. > etc
I want to play a local sound file for each synonym based on the text which obviously changes every time a new word is input.
It works using a switch statement but it means a lot of typing.
I figured a way using googles text-to-speech synthesis engine but I want to use local mp3 which are better quality. The TTS quality is terrible in Firefox but ok in Chrome so I want to use local files with real human voices.
Any ideas to avoid typing lots of case or if statements?
// this version works
function english() {
  var word = document.getElementById("input").value;
  switch (word) {
    case "dog":
      dog.play();
      break;
    case "cat":
      cat.play();
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById("error").play();
  }
}

// this version does not work
function english() {
  var word = document.getElementById("rus1").value;
  word.play();
}

           <audio preload="auto" id="dog" src="../audio/english/dog.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
     <audio preload="auto" id="cat" src="../audio/english/cat.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
       <audio preload="auto" id="собака" src="../audio/russian/dog.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>


           <script>
           this.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
             find()
              }
                })
              function find()
               {
              var word = document.getElementById("input").value;
             switch(word) {

               case "cat": case "кошка": eng1 = "cat" ; rus1 = "кошка" ; break;
               case "dog": case "собака": eng1 = "dog" ; rus1 = "собака" ;  break;

              default: eng1 = "" ; rus1 = ""; 
               }
               document.getElementById("eng1").innerHTML = eng1;
               document.getElementById("rus1").innerHTML = rus1;

                }

                ****************************************************


                </script>

So I take the word in var rus1 (eg собака) and then use it to play the audio rus1.play() = собака.play()

Use an object to store the words to be looked up, along with the path to the audio file to be played, then lookup the word the user typed against the keys of the object.

Also, if you would like a full example with updated logic, I would suggest you edit the question to include a full working demo of the issue

Can you please use the 'Edit' link under the question to add more info, as code in comments is very hard to read.

So I take the name in var rus1 (eg собака)  and then use the textContent to play the audio   rus1.play()    = собака.play()

hi , is my code sufficient.  Do you also  need the HTML code?
